# How do I insert 3 variables into same table cell and separate them with a "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add three variables into the same table cell and separate them by a / so the BR/BA column will have an entry like this: 2/2/0, below is my feeble attempt which ofcourse is returning syntax errors, how do I do it? thanks, Adam

```
<table class="listing" summary="Property list">
<tr class="header">

  <th>Property Address</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Sq Ft</th>
  <th>BR/BA</th>
  <th>Type</th>
</tr>
<% @properties.each do |property| %>
<tr>

  <td><%= link_to(property.address, {:action => 'show', :id => property.id}) %></td>
  <td class="center"><%= property.price %></td>
  <td class="center"><%= property.sq_ft %></td>
  <td class="center"><%= {property.bedrooms "/" property.bathrooms "/" property.half_bathrooms} %></td>
  <td class="center"><%= property.property_type %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just put each variable separately with a "/" between them, i.e., <%= %> around each.

Comment: thanks Dave, just tried that and it worked, only thing is the quotes were unnecessary and gave this output 5 "/" 6 "/" 1 but after removing them and only using / it looked good: 5/6/1, cheers, Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[property.bedrooms,property.bathrooms,property.half_bathrooms].join("/")`

assuming each attribute/method returns a string.

Comment: they are integers in the table but this worked perfectly, thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating strings in Ruby is done with `+`.

`property.bedrooms + "/" + property.bathrooms + "/" + property.half_bathrooms`

Also, in general, any time you post in your question "I have syntax errors" it would be helpful if you posted what those syntax errors are.

Comment: Since one or more of your attributes are numbers, when you apply the '+' operator, Ruby assumes you're doing addition, and then complains when you try to add a string to a number. If you wanted to use this method, call .to_s on the attributes first.

Answer (score 1):

You could add 3 fields

```
attr_accessor :bedrooms, :bathrooms, :half_bathrooms

before_save :combine_cols

def combine_cols
    self.brba = "#{bedrooms}/#{bathrooms}/#{half_bathrooms}"
end

def brba=(val)
    bedrooms, bathrooms, half_bathrooms = val.split('/')
end
```

This is just from top of my head so might not work exactly as is.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the other answer was quicker to try and worked first time so didn't try this out, thanks anyway

Comment: Thats fine. I noticed that your problem was actually much simpler than I had first thought but I had already written this :D